# How to read HDF5 files in Python

Tags: python, hdf5

I am trying to read data from hdf5 file in Python. I can read the hdf5 file using `h5py`, but I cannot figure out how to access data within the file.

### My code

```
import h5py    
import numpy as np    
f1 = h5py.File(file_name,'r+')
```

This works and the file is read. But how can I access data inside the file object `f1`?

Comment: If the file holds a Keras model, you will probably want to [load it with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074549/how-to-load-a-model-from-an-hdf5-file-in-keras) instead.

Comment: Is an `hdf5` file different from an `hdf` file? I have `hdf`s (they are several bands of images), but I cannot figure out how to open them.

Comment: df = numpy.read_hdf(fileName.hdf5) -> this stores the data into a numpy dataframe that you can use.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

### Read HDF5

```
import h5py
filename = "file.hdf5"

with h5py.File(filename, "r") as f:
    # Print all root level object names (aka keys) 
    # these can be group or dataset names 
    print("Keys: %s" % f.keys())
    # get first object name/key; may or may NOT be a group
    a_group_key = list(f.keys())[0]

    # get the object type for a_group_key: usually group or dataset
    print(type(f[a_group_key])) 

    # If a_group_key is a group name, 
    # this gets the object names in the group and returns as a list
    data = list(f[a_group_key])

    # If a_group_key is a dataset name, 
    # this gets the dataset values and returns as a list
    data = list(f[a_group_key])
    # preferred methods to get dataset values:
    ds_obj = f[a_group_key]      # returns as a h5py dataset object
    ds_arr = f[a_group_key][()]  # returns as a numpy array
```

### Write HDF5

```
import h5py

# Create random data
import numpy as np
data_matrix = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10, 3))

# Write data to HDF5
with h5py.File("file.hdf5", "w") as data_file:
    data_file.create_dataset("dataset_name", data=data_matrix)
```

See [h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html) for more information.

### Alternatives

- JSON: Nice for writing human-readable data; VERY commonly used ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795053/562769))
- CSV: Super simple format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585079/562769))
- pickle: A Python serialization format ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245595/562769))
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) ([Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python)): More compact representation ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43442194/562769))
- [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format) ([Python package](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html)): Nice for matrices ([read & write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41586571/562769))
- XML: exists too *sigh* ([read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912483/562769) & [write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605831/562769))

For your application, the following might be important:

- Support by other programming languages
- Reading / writing performance
- Compactness (file size)

See also: [Comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats)

In case you are rather looking for a way to make configuration files, you might want to read my short article [Configuration files in Python](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/)

Comment: To get the data in the HDF5 datasets as a numpy array, you can do `f[key].value`

Comment: As of `h5py` version 2.1: "The property `Dataset.value`, which dates back to h5py 1.0, is deprecated and will be removed in a later release. This property dumps the entire dataset into a NumPy array. Code using `.value` should be updated to use NumPy indexing, using `mydataset[...]` or `mydataset[()]` as appropriate."

Comment: I am using Julia's hdf5 library and the read operation is much faster (would include it as answer, but OP asked for python).  The same hdf5 file read takes forever in h5py, however it is very manageable in Julia, worth learning to program in Julia just for this one problem.  The only issue I had with Julia was that it didn't handle null terminated strings correctly, which for me was a bit of a roadblock.

Comment: Commenting on the answer itself, the list operation in the read  version causes python to freeze.  If I just do f[a_group_key] it works at the proper speed.

Comment: @demongolem: you should not use the listing of all keys of you already know which one you want to use. I have done it here to have a self-contained example that requires least amount of work to get something running.

Comment: If the images are saved as an 1-D array, and different images in the dataset are saved with arrys of different dimensions, is there any particular approach to retrieve the RGB images? Further details are available in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589501/how-can-i-read-hdf5-files-stored-as-1-d-array-and-view-them-as-images

Answer (score 42):

**Reading the file**

```
import h5py

f = h5py.File(file_name, mode)
```

**Studying the structure of the file by printing what HDF5 groups are present**

```
for key in f.keys():
    print(key) #Names of the root level object names in HDF5 file - can be groups or datasets.
    print(type(f[key])) # get the object type: usually group or dataset
```

**Extracting the data**

```
#Get the HDF5 group; key needs to be a group name from above
group = f[key]

#Checkout what keys are inside that group.
for key in group.keys():
    print(key)

# This assumes group[some_key_inside_the_group] is a dataset, 
# and returns a np.array:
data = group[some_key_inside_the_group][()]
#Do whatever you want with data

#After you are done
f.close()
```

Comment: `for key in data.keys():
    print(key) #Names of the groups in HDF5 file.` this can be replace by `list(data)`

Comment: to know exact structure with all variable use : `data.visit(print) `

Comment: just fyi, the f in h5py.File(...) should be capitalized.

Comment: @dannykim Done.

Comment: Important: `data.close()` is needed at the end.

Comment: ERROR python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py:313: H5pyDeprecationWarning: dataset.value has been deprecated. Use dataset[()] instead.
  "Use dataset[()] instead.", H5pyDeprecationWarning)

Comment: It should be (the horrific new syntax): `data = group[some_key_inside_the_group][()]`

Answer (score 28):

you can use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_hdf(filename,key)
```

Comment: You should not rely on the Pandas implementation unless you are storing dataframes. read_hdf relies on the HDF file to be in a certain structure; also there is no pd.write_hdf, so you could only use it one-way. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641246/pandas-cant-read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py/33644128#33644128).

Comment: Pandas does have a writing function. See [pd.DataFrame.to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple function I just wrote which reads a .hdf5 file generated by the save_weights function in keras and returns a dict with layer names and weights:

```
def read_hdf5(path):

    weights = {}

    keys = []
    with h5py.File(path, 'r') as f: # open file
        f.visit(keys.append) # append all keys to list
        for key in keys:
            if ':' in key: # contains data if ':' in key
                print(f[key].name)
                weights[f[key].name] = f[key].value
    return weights
```

https://gist.github.com/Attila94/fb917e03b04035f3737cc8860d9e9f9b.

Haven't tested it thoroughly but does the job for me.

Comment: This function seems to display all the contents in the .h5 file. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

To read the content of .hdf5 file as an array, you can do something as follow

```
> import numpy as np 
> myarray = np.fromfile('file.hdf5', dtype=float)
> print(myarray)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use below code to data read and convert into numpy array

```python
import h5py
f1 = h5py.File('data_1.h5', 'r')
list(f1.keys())
X1 = f1['x']
y1=f1['y']
df1= np.array(X1.value)
dfy1= np.array(y1.value)
print (df1.shape)
print (dfy1.shape)
```

Preferred method to read dataset values into a numpy array:

```
import h5py
# use Python file context manager:
with h5py.File('data_1.h5', 'r') as f1:
    print(list(f1.keys()))  # print list of root level objects
    # following assumes 'x' and 'y' are dataset objects
    ds_x1 = f1['x']  # returns h5py dataset object for 'x'
    ds_y1 = f1['y']  # returns h5py dataset object for 'y'
    arr_x1 = f1['x'][()]  # returns np.array for 'x'
    arr_y1 = f1['y'][()]  # returns np.array for 'y'
    arr_x1 = ds_x1[()]  # uses dataset object to get np.array for 'x'
    arr_y1 = ds_y1[()]  # uses dataset object to get np.array for 'y'
    print (arr_x1.shape)
    print (arr_y1.shape)
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the file, otherwise the file may get corrupted.

Comment: Thank you. It is probably the best way to open a .hdf5 data file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have named datasets in the hdf file then you can use the following code to read and convert these datasets in numpy arrays:

```
import h5py
file = h5py.File('filename.h5', 'r')

xdata = file.get('xdata')
xdata= np.array(xdata)
```

If your file is in a different directory you can add the path in front of`'filename.h5'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from keras.models import load_model 

h= load_model('FILE_NAME.h5')
```

Comment: This is how we load a saved NN model in Keras. I think this question is more general and noting to do with Keras.

Comment: When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a Nail :-).

Answer (score 1):

#### Reading

Use the [`visititems`](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html?highlight=visititems#h5py.Group.visititems) function from [`h5py`](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/quick.html). The callback function is called through all the hierarchy: groups and datasets.

```
import h5py

# Open the HDF5 file in read mode
file_path = 'your_file.h5'

with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as file:
    # Function to recursively print the HDF5 dataset hierarchy
    def print_hdf5_item(name, obj):
        # name is in path format like /group1/group2/dataset
        if isinstance(obj, h5py.Group):
            # Do something like creating a dictionary entry
            print(f'Group: {name}')
        elif isinstance(obj, h5py.Dataset):
            # Do something with obj like converting to a pandas.Series 
            # and storing to a dictionary entry
            print(f'Dataset: {name}')

    # Visit all items in the HDF5 file and print their names
    file.visititems(print_hdf5_item)
```

or use [`pandas.read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html#pandas.read_hdf):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_hdf('./store.h5')
```

Notice that your data might not map directly to a DataFrame. The former option is more flexible.

---

#### Writing

If using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf):

```
# df is a DataFrame object
df.to_hdf('database.h5', 'group/subgroup', table=True, mode='a')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a dataset. If you take a look at the quickstart guide, it shows you that you need to use the file object in order to create a dataset. So, `f.create_dataset` and then you can read the data. This is explained in the [docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data).

Answer (score 0):

Using bits of answers from this question and the latest [doc](https://h5py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/high/dataset.html), I was able to extract my numerical arrays using

```
import h5py
with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as h5f:
    h5x = h5f[list(h5f.keys())[0]]['x'][()]
```

Where `'x'` is simply the X coordinate in my case.

Answer (score 0):

use this it works fine for me

```
    weights = {}

    keys = []
    with h5py.File("path.h5", 'r') as f: 
        f.visit(keys.append) 
        for key in keys:
            if ':' in key: 
                print(f[key].name)     
                weights[f[key].name] = f[key][()]
    return weights

print(read_hdf5())
```

**if you are using the h5py<='2.9.0'
then you can use**

```
    weights = {}

    keys = []
    with h5py.File("path.h5", 'r') as f: 
        f.visit(keys.append) 
        for key in keys:
            if ':' in key: 
                print(f[key].name)     
                weights[f[key].name] = f[key].value
    return weights

print(read_hdf5())
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a wrapper of h5py, [`H5Attr`](https://github.com/syrte/h5attr), that allows you to load hdf5 data easily via attributes such as `group.dataset` (equivalent to the original `group['dataset']`) with IPython/Jupyter tab completion.

The code is [here](https://github.com/syrte/h5attr).
Here are some use examples, you can try the code below yourself

```
# create example HDF5 file for this guide
import h5py, io
file = io.BytesIO()
with h5py.File(file, 'w') as fp:
    fp['0'] = [1, 2]
    fp['a'] = [3, 4]
    fp['b/c'] = 5
    fp.attrs['d'] = 's'

# import package
from h5attr import H5Attr

# open file
f = H5Attr(file)

# easy access to members, with tab completion in IPython/Jupyter
f.a, f['a']

# also work for subgroups, but note that f['b/c'] is more efficient
# because it does not create f['b']
f.b.c, f['b'].c, f['b/c']

# access to HDF5 attrs via a H5Attr wrapper
f._attrs.d, f._attrs['d']

# show summary of the data
f._show()
# 0   int64 (2,)
# a   int64 (2,)
# b/  1 members

# lazy (default) and non-lazy mode
f = H5Attr(file)
f.a  # <HDF5 dataset "a": shape (2,), type "<i8">

f = H5Attr(file, lazy=False)
f.a  # array([3, 4])
```