# Pandas can't read hdf5 file created with h5py

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, h5py

I get pandas error when I try to read HDF5 format files that I have created with h5py. I wonder if I am just doing something wrong?

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
h5_file = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w')
h5_file.create_dataset('zeros', data=np.zeros(shape=(3, 5)), dtype='f')
h5_file.close()
pd_file = pd.read_hdf('test.h5', 'zeros')
```

gives an error:
TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed

I tried to specify key set to '/zeros' (as I would do it with h5py when reading the file) with no luck.

If I use pandas.HDFStore to read it in, I get an empty store back:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
>>> store
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
Empty
```

I have no troubles reading just created file back with h5py:

```
h5_back = h5py.File('test.h5', 'r')
h5_back['/zeros']
<HDF5 dataset "zeros": shape (3, 5), type "<f4">
```

Using these versions:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

pd.__version__
'0.16.2'
h5py.__version__
'2.5.0'
```

Many thanks in advance,
Masha

Comment: See also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9539

Answer (score 20):

I've worked a little on the `pytables` module in `pandas.io` and from what I know pandas interaction with HDF files is limited to specific structures that pandas understands.  To see what these look like, you can try

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.Series(np.zeros((3,5),dtype=np.float32).to_hdf('test.h5','test')
```

If you open 'test.h5' in [HDFView](https://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/hdfview/), you will see a path `/test` with 4 items that are needed to recreate the `DataFrame`.

[image: HDFView of test.h5]

So I think your only option for reading in NumPy arrays is to read them in directly and then  convert these to Pandas objects.

Comment: I wanted to stitch to Pandas, but looks like I have to keep h5py dependency. Thank you so much for your response!

Comment: The code doesn't work: there is a lack of parentheses and Series is 1D but data is 2D. Possibly you wanted to type
`pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3, 5), dtype=np.float32)).to_hdf("test.h5", "test")`