# Reading hdf5 datasets with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, hdf5

I'm trying to open a group-less hdf5 file with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.read_hdf('foo.hdf5')
```

but I get an error:

> TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed

I tried solving this by assigning a `key`:

```
foo = pd.read_hdf('foo.hdf5','key')
```

which works if `key` was a group, but the file has no groups, but rather several datasets in the highest hdf structure. i.e. the structure of the working file is: Groups --> Datasets, while the structure of the not working file is: Datasets. Both work fine when opening them with h5py, where I would use:

```
f = h5py.File('foo.hdf5','r')
```

and

```
dset = f['dataset']
```

to view a dataset. Any ideas how to read this in pandas?

Comment: what happens if you try: `df = pd.read_hdf('foo.hdf5', 'dataset')`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Pandas can't read hdf5 file created with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641246/pandas-cant-read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'are confused by different terminology - Pandas's HDF store `key` is a full path i.e. `Group + DataSet_name`...

demo:

```
In [67]: store = pd.HDFStore(r'D:\temp\.data\hdf\test.h5')

In [68]: store.append('dataset1', df)

In [69]: store.append('/group1/sub_group1/dataset2', df)

In [70]: store.groups
Out[70]:
<bound method HDFStore.groups of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: D:\temp\.data\hdf\test.h5
/dataset1                              frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->9,ncols->2,indexers->[index])
/group1/sub_group1/dataset2            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->9,ncols->2,indexers->[index])>

In [71]: store.items
Out[71]:
<bound method HDFStore.items of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: D:\temp\.data\hdf\test.h5
/dataset1                              frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->9,ncols->2,indexers->[index])
/group1/sub_group1/dataset2            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->9,ncols->2,indexers->[index])>

In [72]: store.close()

In [73]: x = pd.read_hdf(r'D:\temp\.data\hdf\test.h5', 'dataset1')

In [74]: x.shape
Out[74]: (9, 2)

In [75]: x = pd.read_hdf(r'D:\temp\.data\hdf\test.h5', '/group1/sub_group1/dataset2')

In [76]: x.shape
Out[76]: (9, 2)
```

Comment: The output is 
``` <bound method HDFStore.items of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'> File path: /path/foo.hdf5 Empty> ```

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of forgetting to close a file. I just tried opening and closing it with h5py, as I usually do, and it's working fine. I also tried creating 2 new hdf5 files. One has a structure: Group --> several datasets, and the other: several datasets. The first opens normally with pandas using the name of the group as a key, the second does not.

Comment: @hsnee, what do you mean saying `Group`? Could you update your question with the not working example?

Comment: By groups, I mean exactly what they refer to in the HDF5 terminology hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/09_Groups.html

Comment: OK, i guess `Group == key` (in Pandas terminology). Could you upload somewhere a small `h5` file which you can't open (which is not working) - it's going to be hard to help you, not being able to reproduce the problem...