# From CSV file format to HDF5

Tags: csv, hdf5, file-format, file-conversion

I work on database project for university and I need a way to convert CSV files into HDF5 formats. Does anyone know how to do that? What is the best way? Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert large csv to hdf5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203161/convert-large-csv-to-hdf5), [Write a large csv file to hdf5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620478/how-to-write-a-large-csv-file-to-hdf5-in-python)

Comment: You could write a Python script (using the `csv` and `h5py` modules)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203161/convert-large-csv-to-hdf5