# Trying to size down HDF5 File by changing index field types using h5py

Tags: python, h5py

I have a very large CSV File (~12Gb) that looks something like this:

> posX,posY,posZ,eventID,parentID,clockTime
>   -117.9853515625,60.2998046875,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -117.9853515625,60.32909393310547,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -117.9560546875,60.2998046875,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -117.9560546875,60.32909393310547,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -117.92676544189453,60.2998046875,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -117.92676544189453,60.32909393310547,0.29499998688697815,0,0,0
>   -118.04051208496094,60.34012985229492,4.474999904632568,0,0,0
>   -118.04051208496094,60.36941909790039,4.474999904632568,0,0,0
>   -118.04051208496094,60.39870834350586,4.474999904632568,0,0,0

I want to convert this CSV File into the HDF5 Format using the library h5py while also lowering the total file size by setting the field / index types i.G. saying:

Save posX, posY and posZ as float32. Save eventID, parentID and clockTime as int32 or something along those lines.

Note: I need to chunk the data in some form when I read it in to avoid Memory Errors.

However I am unable to get the wished result. What I have tried so far:
Using Pandas own methods following this guide:    [How to write a large csv file to hdf5 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620478/how-to-write-a-large-csv-file-to-hdf5-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
This creates the file but im somehow unable to change the types and the file remains too big (~10.7Gb). The field types are float64 and int64.

I also tried to split the CSV up into parts (using split -n x myfile.csv) before working with the increments. I ran into some data errors in the beginning and end on each file which I was able to fix by removing said lines using sed. Then I tried out the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py

PATH_csv = "/home/MYNAME/Documents/Workfolder/xaa" #xaa is my csv increment
DATA_csv = pd.read_csv(PATH_csv)

with h5py.File("pct_data-hdf5.h5", "a") as DATA_hdf:
    dset = DATA_hdf.create_dataset("posX", data=DATA_csv["posX"], dtype="float32")
```

Sadly this created the file and the table but didn't write any data into it.

**Expectation**
Creating a HDF5 File containing the data of a large CSV file while also changing the variable type of each index.

*If something is unclear please ask me for clarification. Im still a beginner!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the `numpy` module?
It has a handy function (`genfromtxt`) to read CSV data with headers into a Numpy array. You define the dtype. The array is suitable for loading into HDF5 with the `h5py.create_dataset()` function.

See code below. I included 2 print statements. The first shows the dtype names created from the CSV headers. The second shows how you can access the data in the numpy array by field (column) name.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

PATH_csv = 'SO_55576601.csv'
csv_dtype= ('f8', 'f8', 'f8', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4' )

csv_data = np.genfromtxt(PATH_csv, dtype=csv_dtype, delimiter=',', names=True)

print (csv_data.dtype.names)
print (csv_data['posX'])

with h5py.File('SO_55576601.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    dset = h5f.create_dataset('CSV_data', data=csv_data)

h5f.close()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I did try to run this code using a 3.7gb big CSV File but sadly ran out of Memory for some reason (Having 16gb in my System). After using a ~800mb big CSV file it did however worked out as intended, even after taking up to ~8gb of RAM while I ran the script.

Comment: My example used your small data snippet in the OP. I didn't do any memory testing for large data sets. Based on your results, you will have to break your CSV data into separate files (with headers). Then you can `create_dataset()` on the first read/write, then read more data, resize the dataset, and write more data. See these SO posts for examples: [incremental-writes-to-hdf5-with-h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655588) and [how-to-append-data-to-one-specific-dataset-in-a-hdf5-file-with-h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072859)