# How to import a combined CSV file as a dataset under the subgroup /ds1?

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to collect all CSV files into one HDF5 and import them as a dataset under the subgroup ds1. I tried the following code but I don't get what I want:

```
import h5py
import numpy.random
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds1")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
#Create a HDF5 file
xxx3 = "xxx3.h5py";
xxx3 = h5py.File(xxx3, "w");
file=pd.HDFStore('/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds1','w')
IR= xxx3.create_group("/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds1");
XAFS = xxx3.create_group("/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds2");
combined_csv.csv=pd.read_csv('/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds1combined_csv.csv')
file.put('combined_csv.csv',combined_csv.csv,format='table',data_columns=True)
xxx3.close()
```

Comment: I don't use `pandas`, so can't comment that code. It would be simpler (IMHP) to read the CSV files with NumPy's `genfromtxt()` and load the created arrays directly into HDF5 with `h5py` or `Pytables` (tables).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you only create group objects in the H5 file xxx3 in the code above. (`xxx3.create_group()`)

This is what your code would like if you read the data with NumPy and load into HDF5 with h5py. The `np.genfromtxt()` arguments depend on the contents of your CSV. You may need to adjust based on your data.

```
#Create a HDF5 file
import numpy as np
xxx3 = h5py.File("xxx3.h5py", "w");
rec_arr = np.genfromtxt("/root/Desktop/file/data/dataset/ds1combined_csv.csv",delimiter=',' ,names=True,encoding=None)
IR= xxx3.create_dataset("/ds1",data=rec_arr)
xxx3.close()
```

There's another example here:
[SO 55576601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580253/10462884)