# Python read .h5 file

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am having trouble reading an HDF5 file in python.
 If I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_hdf('pepper_experiments.h5','handover')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot create a storer if the object is not existing nor a value are passed
```

[The h5 file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Y6r.png)

Does anyone have an idea why it is not working?

Comment: You can probably refer to this answer, the idea is to read it with numpy and then convert it to pandas dataframe.
[Pandas can't read hdf5 file created with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33641246/pandas-cant-read-hdf5-file-created-with-h5py)

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the link. Could you might help me with what to write? I am not really understanding what to write after the two imports. Sry, but I'm really an absolute python beginner but need this for one project.

Comment: See also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9539