# What is h5 model in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, model, keras

I came across an h5 model in Keras for image recognition.
But I am not sure what does the file extension refers to.

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Possibly [HDF5 Model](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/whatishdf5.html) - See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074549/how-to-load-a-model-from-an-hdf5-file-in-keras

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You mean a HDF5/H5 file, which is a file format to store structured data, its not a model by itself. Keras saves models in this format as it can easily store the weights and model configuration in a single file.

Comment: Thanks for short and totally clear answer. It helps me!