# Python h5py use group of closed file

Tags: python, h5py

I am using hdf5 files to store calibration data. Now I want to use them. But i don't want keep the file open.
I whant to do something like this:

```
fileHandle = h5py.File('calibration.hdf', 'r')
self.xcalib = fileHandle['x']
fileHandle.close()
```

And then just use xcalib independent of the file. the Problem is now that xcalib is just a h5py group object and will be close when the file is close. Is there a simple way to make it work?
so that xcalib is eg. a normal dict. (there are multiple groups and datasets inside)

thanx for every helping comment :)

Edit:
So is there no easy way to just make one complete group "offline"?

```
fileHandle['x']
```

contains multiple groups and datasets and i want it all copied or whatever.
So doing

```
dict(fileHandle['x'])
```

just returns

```
{'0': <HDF5 group "/x/0" (4 members)>, '1': <HDF5 group "/x/1" (4 members)>, '2': <HDF5 group "/x/2" (4 members)>, '3': <HDF5 group "/x/3" (4 members)>}
```

And when i close the file those HDF5 groups are closed to.

Comment: You basically answered your own question... store the data in a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read HDF5 files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170623/how-to-read-hdf5-files-in-python)