# Convert a saved .h5 file to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, python, json, keras

I used a pre-made model with Keras for training a data-set about URLs. results are saved in a .h5 format and I am wondering if I could convert that saved .h5 file to JSON so that I could see the results and apply the JSON file in my system that separates bad URLs from good URLs. I also want to avoid re-training again if possible.

Comment: You can refer to the answers at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170623/how-to-read-hdf5-files-in-python

Comment: I needed it to convert to json so that I could call that json file using javascript and get the data from it

Comment: You can refer the answers here for saving as json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/how-do-i-write-json-data-to-a-file

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion

For example, let’s say you have saved a Keras model named model.h5 to your tmp/ directory. To convert your model using the TensorFlow.js converter, you can run the following command:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras /tmp/model.h5 /tmp/tfjs_model
```

Answer (score 0):

At first

```
!sudo pip3 install tensorflowjs
```

Then

```
!sudo tensorflowjs_converter
```

Just replace model.h5 with your trained weight

```
!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras '/content/drive/MyDrive/model.h5' "/content/drive/MyDrive/json"
```

you are good to go your file will me converted!