# ValueError: test_size=0 should be either positive and smaller than the number of samples 0 or a float in the (0,1) range

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, python-3.7

```
X= data
X_data= 'trained.h5'
#Labels
Y_data = X_data[:,(X_data.shape[1]-1)]
#Training Data
X_data = X_data[:,0:(X_data.shape[1]-1)]
x_tr,x_ts,y_tr,y_ts = train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=0.3,random_state=10)
```

Error comes 
 '(0,1) range'.format(test_size, n_samples))

ValueError: test_size=0 should be either positive and smaller than the number of samples 0 or a float in the (0,1) range

Comment: can you try printing the shapes of Y_data and X_data  ?

Comment: basically i just want to split the data. and ```x_tr,x_ts,y_tr,y_ts = train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=0.3,random_state=10)```` error occur in this line

Comment: yes. I get that. for that, if we know, what is the shape of X_data and Y_data, we will have a better idea of why it gives this error. 
all you need to do is print(X_data.shape) and print(Y_data.shape) and see what it gives, and add it to your question, which will be of nice use for us to debug. Thanks

Comment: i try to run but  this error comes````Y_data = X_data[:,(X_data.shape[1]-1)]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'```

Comment: there you go. that's the problem. you need to know how to read data from .h5 files. there are lot of methods, mentioned in this thread, which will be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170623/how-to-read-hdf5-files-in-python

Comment: or is it a typo ? instead of using X, you are using X_data ?

Comment: yes its typo...and i read the file using ```filename = "trained.h5"
dataset = h5py.File(filename,'r')```

Comment: shall i close this question marking it as typo ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan but my error is solved and still occur ``ValueError: test_size=0 should be either positive and smaller than the number of samples 0 or a float in the (0,1) range

Comment: what is the shape of your Y ? coz it clearly says 
" the number of samples 0 "

Comment: Do you mean dataset? its images

Comment: yea. but the size is 0. what output you get when you print the size ?

Comment: when I print, its come is (0,)

Comment: Thats why. You dont have any data. Something wrong in reading h5 file

Comment: Thanks, @venkatakrishnan, can you guide me further reading .h5 , because with I print .h5 gives an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170623/how-to-read-hdf5-files-in-python this link must help you.