# Changing HDF5 compression filter via h5py

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

How to read a dataset that is compressed via `lzf` compression filter and change it to native HDF5 third party filters like `szip` or `zlib`? Would simply reading it as shown in [How to read HDF5 files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170623/how-to-read-hdf5-files-in-python), and writing it with compression specified when writing a dataset work?

Comment: You can't _change_ the compression of a dataset once it has been created, but you could certainly use the approach you linked to create a _new_ dataset, either in the same file or a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bnaecker  said, you can copy the existing dataset and create a new one using a different compression filter. The new dataset can be in the same file or a new one. Note: `szip` requires special licensing, so I created an example going from `lzf` to `gzip`. See example below. The process is the same for any 2 compression filters. Just change `compression=value`.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

filename = "SO_64582861.h5"

# Create random data

arr1 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(10, 3))

# Create intial HDF5 file
with h5py.File(filename, "w") as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset("ds_lzf", data=arr1, compression="lzf")
  
# Re-Open HDF5 file in 'append' mode
# Copy ds_lzf to ds_gzip with different compression setting
# could also copy to a second HDF5 file
with h5py.File(filename, "a") as h5f:
    # List all groups
    print("Keys: %s" % h5f.keys())
    arr2 = h5f["ds_lzf"][:]
    h5f.create_dataset("ds_gzip", data=arr2, compression="gzip")
```